# How do I reload a module in an active Julia session after an edit?

Tags: module, julia

**2018 Update:** Be sure to check all the responses, as the answer to this question has changed multiple times over the years. At the time of this update, the `Revise.jl` answer is probably the best solution.

I have a file "/SomeAbsolutePath/ctbTestModule.jl", the contents of which are:

```
module ctbTestModule
export f1
f1(x) = x + 1
end
```

I fire up Julia in a terminal, which runs "~/.juliarc.jl". The startup code includes the line:

```
push!(LOAD_PATH, "/SomeAbsolutePath/")
```

Hence I can immediately type into the Julia console:

```
using ctbTestModule
```

to load my module. As expected `f1(1)` returns `2`. Now I suddenly decide I want to edit `f1`. I open up "/SomeAbsolutePath/ctbTestModule.jl" in an editor, and change the contents to:

```
module ctbTestModule
export f1
f1(x) = x + 2
end
```

I now try to reload the module in my active Julia session. I try

```
using ctbTestModule
```

but `f1(1)` still returns `2`. Next I try:

```
reload("ctbTestModule")
```

as suggested [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4008), but `f1(1)` still returns `2`. Finally, I try:

```
include("/SomeAbsolutePath/ctbTestModule.jl")
```

as suggested [here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/faq/), which is *not* ideal since I have to type out the full absolute path since the current directory might not be "/SomeAbsolutePath". I get the warning message `Warning: replacing module ctbTestModule` which sounds promising, but `f1(1)` still returns `2`.

If I close the current Julia session, start a new one, and type in `using ctbTestModule`, I now get the desired behaviour, i.e. `f1(1)` returns `3`. But obviously I want to do this *without* re-starting Julia.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Other details: Julia v0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thank you for including the 2018 update. Simply because it's been so long since `workspace()` existed in Julia, I'd go so far as to accept miguelmorin's answer now instead of the previously accepted answer that has since become deprecated.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Honestly, I'm not sure what the appropriate etiquette is in this situation. The accepted answer does not necessarily need to be the right one. Rather the FAQ states that it is the one the asker found most helpful. For me, this is the currently accepted answer. Given my 2018 update at the top of my post directs readers in the right direction, I think it is better to just leave things be.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The basis of this problem is the confluence of reloading a module, but not being able to redefine a thing in the module ***Main*** ([see the documentation here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/faq/)) -- that is [at least until the new function workspace() was made available](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/7487) on July 13 2014.  Recent versions of the 0.3 pre-release should have it.

### Before workspace()

Consider the following simplistic module

```
module TstMod
export f

function f()
   return 1
end

end
```

Then use it....

```
julia> using TstMod

julia> f()
1
```

If the function **f**() is changed to *return 2* and the module is reloaded, **f** is in fact updated.  But not redefined in module **Main**.

```
julia> reload("TstMod")
Warning: replacing module TstMod

julia> TstMod.f()
2

julia> f()
1
```

The following warnings make the problem clear

```
julia> using TstMod
Warning: using TstMod.f in module Main conflicts with an existing identifier.

julia> using TstMod.f
Warning: ignoring conflicting import of TstMod.f into Main
```

### Using workspace()

However, the new function **workspace**() clears ***Main*** preparing it for reloading ***TstMod***

```
julia> workspace()

julia> reload("TstMod")

julia> using TstMod

julia> f()
2
```

Also, the previous ***Main*** is stored as ***LastMain***

```
julia> whos()
Base                          Module
Core                          Module
LastMain                      Module
Main                          Module
TstMod                        Module
ans                           Nothing

julia> LastMain.f()
1
```

Comment: +1+Tick Many thanks. Will come back and award bounty once StackOverflow lets me :-)

Comment: `clear!()` and `clear!(:TstMod)` fail for me with `ERROR: invalid redefinition of constant TstMod`. I could not figure out how to use the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/parallel/#Base.Distributed.clear!-Tuple{Any,Any}) of `Base.Distributed.clear!`. @PatrickT, how would you use it?

Comment: What is the solution to this in 2020? None of the posted answers seem to work (reload function is not defined, neither is workspace in 1.5.3). Seems like quite a basic and important feature of an IDE, to clear the environment or reload a specific module.

Comment: Someone who knows the answer to @cbartondock question?

Comment: The package `Revise` did the trick for me

Answer (score 29):

Use the package `Revise`, e.g.

```
Pkg.add("Revise") # do this only once

include("src/my_module.jl")
using Revise
import my_module
```

You may need to start this in a new REPL session. Notice the use of `import` instead of `using`, because `using` does not redefine the function in the `Main` module (as explained by @Maciek Leks and @waTeim).

**Other solutions**: Two advantages of `Revise.jl` compared to `workspace()` are that (1) it is much faster, and (2) it is future-proof, as `workspace()` was deprecated in 0.7, as discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/25166):

```
julia> VERSION
v"0.7.0-DEV.3089"

julia> workspace()
ERROR: UndefVarError: workspace not defined
```

and a GitHub contributor recommended `Revise.jl`:

> Should we add some mesage like "workspace is deprecated, check out Revise.jl instead"?

Even in Julia 0.6.3, the three previous solutions of `workspace()`, `import`, and `reload` fail when a module called other modules, such as `DataFrames`. With all three methods, I got the same error when I called that module the second time in the same REPL:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: all(::DataFrames.##58#59, ::Array{Any,1}) is ambiguous. Candidates: ...
```

I also got many warning messages such as:

```
WARNING: Method definition macroexpand(Module, ANY) in module Compat at /Users/mmorin/.julia/v0.6/Compat/src/Compat.jl:87 overwritten in module Compat at /Users/mmorin/.julia/v0.6/Compat/src/Compat.jl:87.
```

Restarting the Julia session worked, but it was cumbersome. I found [this issue in the Reexport package](https://github.com/simonster/Reexport.jl/issues/14), with a similar error message:

```
MethodError: all(::Reexport.##2#6, ::Array{Any,1}) is ambiguous.
```

and followed the suggestion of one contributor:

> Does this happen without using workspace()? That function is notorious for interacting poorly with packages, which is partly why it was deprecated in 0.7.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've added a banner at the top of the question suggesting that readers look at all the answers (especially this one), since the best solution has changed multiple times over the past few years.

Answer (score 13):

In my humble opinion, the better way is to use `import` from the very beginning instead of `using` for the reported issue.

Consider the module:

```
module ModuleX1
  export produce_text
  produce_text() = begin
    println("v1.0") 
  end
  println("v1.0 loaded")
end
```

Then in REPL:

```
julia> import ModuleX1
v1.0 loaded

julia> ModuleX1.produce_text()
v1.0
```

Update the code of the module and save it:

```
module ModuleX1
  export produce_text
  produce_text() = begin
    println("v2.0")  
  end
  println("v2.0 loaded")
end
```

Next, in the REPL:

```
julia> reload("ModuleX1")
Warning: replacing module ModuleX1
v2.0 loaded

julia> ModuleX1.produce_text()
v2.0
```

Advantages of using `import` over `using`:

- avoiding ambiguity in function calls (*What to call: ModuleX1.produce_text() or produce_text() after reloading?*)
- do not have to call `workspace()` in order to get rid of ambiguity

Disadvantages of using `import` over `using`:

- a fully qualified name in every call for every exported name is needed

Edited: Discarded  "full access to the module, even to the not-exported names" from "Disadvantages..." according to the conversation below.

Comment: This is interesting. One quick question: I thought I could get full access to the non-exported names in a module via `using` as long as I fully qualified the call. Is this not correct?

Answer (score 9):

`workspace()` has been deprecated.

You can `reload("MyModule")` in an active REPL session, and it works as expected: changes made to the source file that contains `MyModule` are reflected in the active REPL session.

This applies to modules that have been brought into scope by either `import MyModule` or `using MyModule`

Comment: You need to use `reload("MyModule")` (i.e. with quotes) because `reload()` takes a string as an argument not a module.

Comment: I have a source file in `src/my_module.jl`. Calling `reload("src/my_module.jl")` gives the `ERROR: LoadError: use 'include' instead of 'reload' to load source files`. That is because of the slash, given that the [source code](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/d55cadc350d426a95fd967121ba77494d08364c8/base/loading.jl#L366-L371) suggests to include the source file if it has a slash. Without the slash, it says `ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Module my_module not found in current path.` @bizzy, how do you use `reload()` with a source file in a sub-directory?

Comment: @bizzy: Found it, I had to add `src/` to the `LOAD_PATH`: `push!(LOAD_PATH, "src/"); reload("my_module")`.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to create a new module from scratch, and tried the different answers with 1.0 and didn’t get a satisfactory result, but I found the following worked for me:

From the Julia REPL in the directory I want to use for my project I run

```
pkg> generate MyModule
```

This creates a subdirectory like the following structure:

```
MyModule
├── Project.toml
└── src
    └── MyModule.jl
```

I put my module code in `MyModule.jl`. I change to the directory `MyModule` (or open it in my IDE) and add a file `Scratch.jl` with the following code:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.activate(".")
using Revise
import MyModule # or using MyModule
```

Then I can add my code to test below and everything updates without reloading the REPL.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that `MyModule` (more like `MyPackage`) will now depend on `Revise.jl` (so installing your package will automatically install Revise), even though the latter is only used for development?

Answer (score 2):

I battled to get Revise.jl to work for me, probably because I also use code generation with OOPMacro `@class` . I had to also call `revise(...)` See https://timholy.github.io/Revise.jl/stable/limitations/#Limitations-1.

I have been struggling with this problem for up to 5 years and finally got something that works for me that don't involve manually running my main module in the IDE repl after EVERY SMALL CHANGE :'(
Here is some of my code I use to force a revise and exit early when running tests when there were revise errors:

```
# Common code I include into my test files now:
using Pkg
using Revise

# force include module
Pkg.activate("MyModule")
include("../src/MyModule.jl")


Pkg.activate("MyModule/test")
using Revise

# if there were any revise errors which means some compilation error or
# some change that requires a manual rerun or restart.
# then force you to fix it, rather that running lying tests..
for (k, e) in Revise.queue_errors
    if !isnothing(e)
        warn(logger, "Something went wrong while revising, you probably have a compile error in this file:")
        throw(e)
    end
end


module TestSomethingModule  
    using Revise
    using MyModule
    revise(MyModule)
    ... 
    # then you can call MyModule.doSomithing in a test and it actually updates
end
```