# how to undo "using module" in Julia?

Tags: module, julia

I ran

```
using myModule
```

but, because `myModule` had runtime errors, I'd like to undo that `using` statement.
Is there a way to do that at the Julia command line?

I know I could simply close and relaunch the Julia REPL, but I'd like to avoid that because it's relatively slow to start (at least, on  Windows).

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028873/how-do-i-reload-a-module-in-an-active-julia-session-after-an-edit

Comment: `workspace()` (see the link provided by @cel above). Make sure you're running the latest stable version of `0.3` (or `0.4`) as earlier versions of `0.3`, e.g. `0.3.0` are a bit buggy with the `workspace()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cited in previous answerd [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028873/how-do-i-reload-a-module-in-an-active-julia-session-after-an-edit),
and refer to Julia [documentation](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/base/?highlight=workspace#Base.workspace):

> workspace()
>
> Replace the top-level module (Main) with a new one,
>   providing a clean workspace. The previous Main module is made
>   available as LastMain. A previously-loaded package can be accessed
>   using a statement such as using LastMain.Package.
>
> This function should only be used interactively.

the right answer is to use `workspace()` function.