# edit source code (and recompile?) julia package

Tags: open-source, julia

I want to edit the source code to a particular Julia package. To make it concrete, let's say I want to add a new distribution to the [`Distributions.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl) package. However, I'm having difficulty finding where the Julia source code is (and imagine once I find it, I may have to rebuild/recompile Julia?). I've added the package with `Pkg.add("Distributions.jl")` but can't find it on my computer (MacOS).

For example, if I wanted to edit a function in Python's `numpy` package, (using Anaconda) I'd navigate to `/Users/MYUSER/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy` and edit the source there. How do I do this in Julia, in particular for the `Distributions.jl` package? Can you point a novice to any references?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @ColinTBowers: edited, thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
Pkg.dir("Distributions")
#Returns "C:\\Users\\Chris\\.julia\\v0.6\\Distributions"
```

You can edit the file directly and execute it using Juno's inline evaluation and that will update it inside the module, so no restarting is necessary like that. [Here's a video I made awhile back on Julia package development](https://youtu.be/tx8DRc7_c9I).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to edit particular method then you could use @edit macro as well:

```
julia> @edit Distributions.Levy()
```

If you use supported editor you'll be in line where method is defined. In vim's statusbar I could see `"~/.julia/v0.6/Distributions/src/univariate/continuous/levy.jl" 102L, 2751C` (so definition in my version starts at line 102 of file levy.jl)

You could set editor which is supported (for example atom, sublime, kate, gedit, emacs, notepad, ... by:

```
julia> ENV["JULIA_EDITOR"] = "vim";
```

and you could do this in ~/.juliarc.jl   (or by `export JULIA_EDITOR=vim` in .bashrc or what your shell allow).

Which editors are supported you could see using (warning: you have to analyse source code!):

```
julia> @edit edit("")
```

Or which will be supported probably looking at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/interactiveutil.jl

**edit:**

Ad recompile: I didn't test it but [Revise.jl](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl) seems very useful!

Answer (score 4):

Some of the answers above are outdated / partial / didn't work for me so I thought I'd
give my two cents here as I had this exact need recently (using Julia 1.5.3).

First of all and unfortunately, `Pkg.dir()` is deprecated and gets a warning when used.

To find the path where a module/package code resides you can use the `Base.pathof(::Module)` function, for example:

```
julia> pathof(HTTP)
"C:\\Users\\User\\.julia\\packages\\HTTP\\IAI92\\src\\HTTP.jl"
```

To edit a module's code you can use the REPL, for example:

```
julia> edit(HTTP)
```

will open your editor at the HTTP module's souce code.

Alternatively, when using **VSCode** you can right click on a function call and use the *Go to Definition* (F12) context menu option and open to the source code in your editor (**Atom** has an equivalent *Go to Declaration* option but it did not work for me).

Note that you can resort to the quick-and-dirty method and just edit the code where you find it or you use a much cleaner way offered by the Julia Pkg module:

```
pkg> develop --local Example
```

This will create a git clone of the Example package under your current project root so you can work on a separate local copy of the package code in a development environment.
To stop working with the dev module use:

```
pkg> free Example
```

For more info refer to the [Julia Pkg module documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/)

Please keep in mind that (as already stated in the answers above) Julia pre-compiles modules on startup only, so unless you are using [Revise.jl](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl) as pointed-out by [Liso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1782955/liso) above, every change to a module's code requires restarting Julia in order to recompile the changed module.
this can be done by typing

```
julia> exit()
```

and running the `using <Module Name>` statement again.

**Edit:** this question is closely related to:
[How to find the path of a package in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61440940/how-to-find-the-path-of-a-package-in-julia)

**Edit:** VSCode's Julia extension has an option for loading Revise.jl when starting the Julia REPL, the default for this option is true.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the source code at `/Users/MYUSER/.julia/v0.6/Distributions/src/`. It was a hidden folder that I didn't see originally...

Comment: Yep, it's the same on Linux. Not sure where it is on Windows... regarding rebuild and recompile: if the package is pre-compiled you will need to restart your session (but everything else will happen automatically). If the package is not pre-compiled then in theory you should just be able to use `workspace`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028873/how-do-i-reload-a-module-in-an-active-julia-session-after-an-edit) for more detail... (Note: I personally tend to restart my session rather than using `workspace`)