# How to find the path of a package in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to find the path to a specific package in Julia. I do not know exactly where it is and I want to use the appropriate path. Is there a function that does this in Julia?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you have it loaded yuou have a `Module` object.

If you have module object you can use `pathof` to find it.

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> pathof(DataFrames)
"/Users/oxinabox/.julia/packages/DataFrames/cdZCk/src/DataFrames.jl"

julia> pathof(DataFrames.PooledArrays)
"/Users/oxinabox/.julia/packages/PooledArrays/yiLq3/src/PooledArrays.jl"
```

If we were a bit broader and wanted the path to a module that wasn't a package, but was either loaded directly, or a submodule, than `pathof` won't work.

For example **LibPQ.jl** has a `Errors` submodule

```
julia> using LibPQ

julia> pathof(LibPQ)
"/Users/oxinabox/.julia/packages/LibPQ/SFs6f/src/LibPQ.jl"

julia> typeof(LibPQ.Errors)
Module

julia> pathof(LibPQ.Errors)
```

the output was `nothing`.

This is as per the [`pathof` documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.pathof-Tuple%7BModule%7D)

> Return the path of the `m.jl` file that was used to import module `m`, or nothing if `m` was not imported from a package.

If you want to track that down there is a trick.
All modules in julia (except `baremodules`) automatically contain a defination for there own `eval` function.
We can look up the location of this function from the method table.

```
julia> module_file(modu) = String(first(methods(getfield(modu, :eval))).file)
module_file (generic function with 1 method)

julia> module_file(LibPQ)
"/Users/oxinabox/.julia/packages/LibPQ/SFs6f/src/LibPQ.jl"

julia> module_file(LibPQ.Errors)
"/Users/oxinabox/.julia/packages/LibPQ/SFs6f/src/exceptions.jl
```

Other than `baremodules` and modules that are not packages, there is one other case where they disagree.

`pathof` resolves module location via the Manifest.
If you change the manfiest after loading a module,
then the module that is loaded will still actually refer to the old location, but the Manifest, and thus `pathof` will think it is at the new location.

```
(11) pkg> dev --local LibPQ
    Cloning git-repo `https://github.com/invenia/LibPQ.jl.git`
  Resolving package versions...
Updating `~/temp/11/Project.toml`
  [194296ae] ~ LibPQ v1.5.0 ⇒ v1.5.0 `dev/LibPQ`
Updating `~/temp/11/Manifest.toml`
  [194296ae] ~ LibPQ v1.5.0 ⇒ v1.5.0 `dev/LibPQ`
   Building LibPQ → `~/temp/11/dev/LibPQ/deps/build.log`

julia> pathof(LibPQ)
"/Users/oxinabox/temp/11/dev/LibPQ/src/LibPQ.jl"

julia> module_file(LibPQ)
"/Users/oxinabox/.julia/packages/LibPQ/SFs6f/src/LibPQ.jl"
```

`pathof` is giving what is arguably the wrong answer (this is true for julia 1.5 at least I suspect it might change in the future.)
but `module_file`, because it looks at what code is actually loaded and records that location at load time, gives the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pathof` to find the location of an imported module (and package if the module was in a package)

```
julia> using Random

julia> pathof(Random)
"C:\\Julia-1.4.1\\share\\julia\\stdlib\\v1.4\\Random\\src\\Random.jl"
```

Answer (score 2):

Julia's standard library (Base) provides a `find_package` function which works as follows:

```
julia> Base.find_package("Random")
"/Applications/Julia-1.3.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/Random/src/Random.jl"

julia> Base.find_package("JSON")
"/Users/logankilpatrick/.julia/packages/JSON/d89fA/src/JSON.jl"
```