# How do I find out my package version in Julia?

Tags: package, julia, version

How do I find out my package version in Julia? Is there a command which shows the version that's being used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easy to check the version that is installed in the current project environment:

```
(@v1.5) pkg> st DataFrames
Status `D:\.julia\environments\v1.5\Project.toml`
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.22.1 `D:\.julia\dev\DataFrames`
```

It is more difficult to get a version of currently loaded package (that might be different if you e.g. changed project environment or upgraded the package in the same Julia session). For this you can use:

```
julia> using Pkg

(@v1.5) pkg> st DataFrames
Status `D:\.julia\environments\v1.5\Project.toml`
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.22.2

julia> Pkg.TOML.parsefile(joinpath(String(first(methods(getfield(DataFrames, :eval))).file), "..", "..", "Project.toml"))["version"]
"0.22.1"
```

(in this example I have first loaded DataFrames.jl 0.22.1 then after having loaded it upgraded it to 0.22.2)

(you can have find more details why this is needed and when it fails [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61440940/how-to-find-the-path-of-a-package-in-julia/63883681))

Comment: You can also just do: `st` and it will give you all your packages and their versions.

Comment: `pathof` has been fixed for 1.6 so no need to jump through hoops with `methods` etc. In addition, you can use `pkgdir(DataFrames)`, which gives the package root folder. I would also advise against changing package environment in runtime.

Comment: The 1.6 fix is great, bravo. I agree changing package environment at runtime is not advisable. The problem is that this is one of the most common root causes of issues I get reported regards how DataFrames.jl works.