# Reloading module after change Julia v1.0

Tags: julia

When debugging my code I have to frequently change one module, reload it, and test it, including plotting some results of my code. The only way I currently know to do this with Julia 1.0 is to restart the kernel and reload the modules that way. The problem is that this makes me lose 20 or so seconds each time waiting for my plotting module to compile.

Is there a way to reload the module I am tweaking without unloading e.g. Gadfly so that I don't have to keep recompiling my plotting module?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028873/how-do-i-reload-a-module-in-an-active-julia-session-after-an-edit See the update to the question and then the relevant answer (i.e. use of Revise.jl)

Comment: Got it - didn't see that the current solution is at the bottom of that page! My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend the [Revise.jl](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl) package which is designed for exactly this.