# How do I reload a module under development in Julia 1.6?

Tags: julia

I know this question has been asked and answered before, but none of the many answers work for me as described.

What is the procedure for reloading a module that I'm working on in Julia (1.6)?

For example, I have

```
module MyModule

export letters

const letters = String('A':'Z')

end
```

and I want the be able to load the module, make changes to `letters` in the module's file, and then reload the module and have those changes reflected in subsequent uses of `letters`. This seems simple enough, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried

```
include("src/MyModule.jl")
using .MyModule
```

but if I change the definition of `letters` in `MyModule.jl` and then

```
include("src/MyModule.jl")
```

`letters` doesn't change, unless I fully qualify its use each time with `Main.MyModule.letters`: `using Main.MyModule; letters` refers, for example, to the old definition.

How do I reload a module under development so that I can refer to its definitions without fully qualifying them (and without having an unqualified shadow definition always lying around)?

Comment: Related discussion: [How do I reload a module in an active Julia session after an edit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028873/how-do-i-reload-a-module-in-an-active-julia-session-after-an-edit)

Comment: @IanWeaver Yes and no. It answers it in several different ways, many of which are clearly outdated, and none of which works.

Comment: Yea, having a bunch of old/conflicting answers can be frustrating. I was referring to the more recent answer in that thread that the OP added to their question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50816280/16402912. I added more details below

Answer (score 5):

I would just use [Revise.jl](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl) and wrap everything in functions:

```
module MyModule

export letters

letters(char_start, char_end) = char_start:char_end |> String

end
```

```
julia> using Revise

julia> includet("src/MyModule.jl")

julia> using .MyModule

julia> letters('l', 'p')
"lmnop"
```

```
module MyModule

export letters

letters(char_start, char_end) = char_start:char_start |> String

end
```

```
julia> letters('l', 'p')
"l"
```

`const` is for defining things that you do not want to modify, so I would not expect your original version to work as expected. Revise.jl should also throw a redefinition error if you try to change it

In general though, it's usually much nicer (and easier too!) to just put everything in a package and use the usual `using`/`import` syntax. [PkgTemplates.jl](https://github.com/invenia/PkgTemplates.jl) is great for this

If you would like to redefine consts though, I would definitely recommend checking out [Pluto.jl](https://github.com/fonsp/Pluto.jl)